# Is Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem a logical equivalence?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal A,\mu)$ be a measure space and $\langle f_n\rangle_{n\in\mathbb N}$ a sequence of integrable functions that converges $\mu$-almost everywhere. By Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem, if $\langle|f_n|\rangle_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is bounded above by an integrable function, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n$ is integrable and
$$\int\!\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n\;\mathrm d\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int\!f_n\;\mathrm d\mu\quad.$$

LDCT cannot be used if we do not assume the said boundedness. For instance, if $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure and $f_n=nI_{[0,1/n]}$, we get $0=1$.

But is the equality false *whenever* we drop this hypothesis? In other words, can "if" be replaced by "if and only if" on the theorem statement? Or is there an integrable non-dominated $\mu$-a. e. convergent sequence (and a measure) for which the equality occurs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The converse does not hold. Take $X = [0,\infty)$ with Lebesgue measure.  Let $a_n$ be a sequence of positive numbers such that $a_n \to 0$ but $\sum_n a_n = \infty$.  (For instance, $a_n = 1/n$ would work.)  Let $b_n = \sum_{i=0}^n a_k$.  Then let $f_n = 1_{[b_{n-1}, b_{n})}$.  Then $f_n \to 0$ a.e. and $\int f_n dm = a_n \to 0$ also.  But if $f$ is a dominating function, we must have $f \ge \sup_n f_n = 1$ which is not integrable.

For a necessary and sufficient condition for convergence, look up the [Vitali convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

There is an interesting version which generalizes the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem:

> Suppose that $(f_n)$ converges almost everywhere to $f$. Furthermore, suppose there exists a sequence $(g_n)$ of positive, integrable functions, which converges in $L^1$ to $g$ such that $|f_n| \leq g_n$ almost everywhere.
>
> Then $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n = \int f$$

Proof: Apply Fatou's lemma to the sequence $h_n = |g_n-g|+|g|+|f|-|f_n-f|\geq 0$.